# Directory not found in Pycharm when running code

Tags: python

I get an error by running my code in pycharm. I get this  message :

> C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file
>   'C:/Users/Melinda/PycharmProjects/untitled/classParticipant.py':
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
I understand that I don't have the Folder named untitled, because I have renamed  it afterwards as Lab4.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4KIr.png)

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Answer (score 2):

You've borked your project by renaming the directory yourself rather than renaming the project from within the IDE.

You need to close and delete the project (do not delete the files when it asks). If you feel unsure about this copy your files to a backup location first. Then reopen the project using "Open" from the file menu.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go that far to delete the project, have a go at going to

```
Settings -> Project -> Project Structure
```

and then removing and re-adding the project root.